# How to implement locking across a network

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I have a desktop application. In this application there many records that users can open and work on. If a user clicks on a record the program will lock the record so no one else can use it. If the record is already locked then the user may still view it but it will be read-only. Many users on our local network can open and work on records.

My first thought is to use the database to manage locks on records. But I am not sure how or if this is the best approach. Is there any programming patterns or ready made solutions I can use?

Comment: Based on your description, it would be easiest to use a source control system, like TFS. But that's because your description is not adequate. Please give more information about the workflow, the kind of data, etc. This will still amount to a question which is too broad, but you might get some useful comments before the question is closed.

Comment: sounds like you want to research ways to implement pessimistic locking. There are plenty of similar Q's on this site.

Comment: You do **not** want to use SQL locking.  SQL locks are based on isolation level and type of DM.  Without your control, SQL locks start with a ROW, then escalate automatically to pages (with multiple rows per page) and eventually the whole table.  Ideally, SQL locks should last milliseconds - not human-editing-intervals.  There are many possible patterns to solve user-session-locking - but they depend on all sorts of details (as John Saunders indicated).

Comment: You are describing pessimistic locking, instead of optimistic locking. Each have their uses. Pessimistic is generally frowned upon because of performance problems. Nevertheless it is sometimes what you need. If that is indeed what you want, you need to have your ADO command start a SQL BEGIN TRAN, keep the same connection object alive, for the life of the process, and when you fetch the record use an UPDLOCK hint.

Comment: I really don't want to lock the record in SQL server. I was thinking maybe I can create a column on the table called 'Locked' (bool). Then when the user clicks on the record the program will check if the Locked flag is true. If its true then it will return true. If it is false then it will set the Locked flag to true. Do you seen anything wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've implemented a similar system for a WPF application accessing a database, however I no longer have access to the source code, I'll try to explain here. The route I took was somewhat different from using the database. Using a [Duplex WCF service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660479/Duplex-Service-in-WCF) you can host a service somewhere (i.e. the database server) from which clients connect. Key things to understand:

- You can make this service generic by having some kind of data type and by making sure each row type has the same type of primary key (e.g. a `long`). In that case, you could have a signature similar to: `bool AcquireLock(string dataType, long id)` or replacing the `bool`/`long` by `bool[]` and `long[]` if users frequently modify a larger number of rows.
- On the server side, you must be able to quickly respond to this request. Consider storing the data in something along the lines of a `Dictionary<String (DataType), Dictionary<User, HashSet<long>>` where the root string is a datatype.
- When someone connects, he can receive a list of all locks for a given data type (e.g. when a screen opens that locks that type of records), while also registering to receive updates for a given data type.
- The socket connection between the client as the server defines that the user is 'connected'. If the socket closes, the server releases all locks for that user, immediately notifying others that the user has lost his lock, making the record available again for editing. (This covers scenarios such as a user disconnecting or killing a process).
- To avoid concurrency issues, make sure a user acquired the lock before allowing him to make any changes. (e.g. `BeginEdit`, check with the server first,  by implementing `IEditableObject` on your view model).
- When a lock is released, the client tells the server if he made changes to the row, so that other clients can update the respective data. When the socket disconnects, assume no changes.
- Nice feature to add: when providing users with a list / update of locks, also provide the user id, so that people can see who is working on what.

This form of 'real time concurrency' provides a much better user experience than providing a way to handle optimistic concurrency problems, and might also be technically easier to implement, depending on your scenario.

Comment: This is great. On your second bullet point will dictionary be in a static class? And, that is great idea sing the duplex service to notify clients. never would have thought of that.

Comment: I used a system very similar to this is a project I did a few years ago.  Another feature that goes well with this is the ability to "subscribe" to a document by the primary key.  The server keeps a list of interested clients and send them a message about changes to things they are subscribed to.  The client subscribes to a key when it's being viewed readonly and can instantly pick up changes when someone edits it.

Comment: The only issue we ran in to was that some people would go home for the weekend leaving a critical file locked.  We eventually implemented a "timeout", and the ability for an admin to forcefully release a lock from a management screen.

Comment: Agree with the timeout that @BradleyUffner mentions. I used a single instance WCF service, so you can keep it in local state or use a static class instead, make it thread safe so you can allow multiple clients on different threads to use it.